# testing canvas object using selenium

Tags: selenium, canvas

I have to test a web page with a canvas object. I need to test the tooltip text that is displayed when you cover over the data points in the canvas object.

How to get the X, Y data points
How to move the mouse to X, Y

Comment: Did you try method scrollto?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `moveToElement` method , in java it seems like the following:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
builder.moveToElement(knownElement, 10, 25).click().build().perform();
```